# Signal SIGSEGV when loading libjvm.dylib on Mac using dlopen

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, java-native-interface

I am trying to get the function pointer to JNI_CReateJVM correct from the libjvm.dylib in Mac. The counterpart in windows is working. So the pointer to the libjvm.dylib (m_jvm_dll) is not null i.e the path to the library is correct. Also m_createJVM_Ptr is not null. So I am definitely getting the pointers. But as soon as I use m_createJVM_Ptr the following Thread1:signal SIGSEGV error shows up in Xcode:

```
->  0x11566c2b4: movl   (%rsi), %eax
0x11566c2b6: leaq   0xf8(%rbp), %rsi
0x11566c2bd: vmovdqu %ymm0, (%rsi)
0x11566c2c1: vmovdqu %ymm7, 0x20(%rsi)
0x11566c2c6: vmovdqu %ymm8, 0x40(%rsi)
0x11566c2cb: vmovdqu %ymm15, 0x60(%rsi)
```

Here is the culprit function.

```
bool JVMInitializer::create_JVM(SettingDlg* inp_settingDlg){
wxString jvm_path;
wxString ij_path;
wxString bioformats_path;
//if (inp_settingDlg)
//{
//  jvm_path = inp_settingDlg->getJVMPath();
//  ij_path = inp_settingDlg->getIJPath();
//  bioformats_path = inp_settingDlg->getBioformatsPath();
//}

//Loading JVM library and methods.
jvm_path = "/Users/dev/Downloads/ImageJ/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib";
#ifdef _WIN32
m_jvm_dll = LoadLibraryW(jvm_path.ToStdWstring().c_str());
#else
m_jvm_dll = dlopen((const char*)jvm_path.mb_str(wxConvUTF8), RTLD_NOW);
#endif
if (m_jvm_dll == nullptr)
    return false;

#ifdef _WIN32
m_createJVM_Ptr = (decltype(&JNI_CreateJavaVM))GetProcAddress(m_jvm_dll, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
#else
m_createJVM_Ptr = (CreateJavaVM_t*) dlsym(m_jvm_dll, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
#endif
if (m_createJVM_Ptr == nullptr)
  return false;

using namespace std;    
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
//Geting absolute path to class file.
wxString exePath = wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath();
exePath = wxPathOnly(exePath);
string imageJPath = "-Djava.class.path=" + exePath + GETSLASH() + "Java_Code" + GETSLASH() + getPathSeparator();
//imageJPath.append(ij_path + getPathSeparator());
//imageJPath.append(bioformats_path);

imageJPath.append(exePath + GETSLASH() + "Java_Code" + GETSLASH() + "ij.jar;");
imageJPath.append(exePath + GETSLASH() + "Java_Code" + GETSLASH() + "SlideBook6Reader.jar;");
imageJPath.append(exePath + GETSLASH() + "Java_Code" + GETSLASH() + "bioformats_package.jar;");

options[0].optionString = const_cast<char*>(imageJPath.c_str());

m_VMargs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;             // minimum Java version
m_VMargs.nOptions = 1;                          // number of options
m_VMargs.options = options;
m_VMargs.ignoreUnrecognized = false;     // invalid options make the JVM init fail

jint rc = m_createJVM_Ptr(&m_pJvm, (void**)&m_pEnv, &m_VMargs);
delete[] options;
if (rc != JNI_OK) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

The fault occurs on jint rc = ..... (7th last line).

Here is the link to source files:
[jvminitializer.cpp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o6qAczmODhE9ucD2a9xHHHwS4ruIoJKO)
[jvminitializer.h](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1myaBHxN702dXWVuBDt07YZhE-sqjq2ie)

So I had run the code without dynamically loading the jvm library and it has worked by directly calling the JNI_CreateJavaVM method but I want it to work with dynamic loading. Also a point to note is that I am using JRE inside the imageJ for dynamic loading which comes with Java 1.8. Thought this info might be relevant.

Comment: Can your code load the JVM without a `SIGSEGV` if you don't call `dlopen()`?

Comment: Yes if I dont use dlopen() the code works fine and JVM is initialized and I can call JNI_createJavaVM without the SIGSEGV.

Comment: Update: The app is working if I open the application from the finder but crashes when it runs from Xcode. This is definitely weird.

Answer (score 0):

**JNI_CreateJavaVM()** intentionally raises (and catches) access violation exception.

Debugger (Visual Studio, XCode, etc.) will typically stop when this exception is raised.

You can configure debugger not to stop when access violation exception is raised, or just ignore this exception and continue execution:

**Visual Studio**: press "Continue".

**XCode**: enter into debugger window: `pr h -s false SIGSEGV`, then press "Continue".